# NullPointerException for Google App Engine Text

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2, nullpointerexception

I have the following Profile bean with `Text` property:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;

public class Profile {
    ... 
    private Text aboutMySelf = null;

    public String getAboutMySelf() {
        return aboutMySelf.getValue();
    }
    public void setAboutMySelf(String aboutMySelf) {
        this.aboutMySelf = new Text(aboutMySelf);
    }
    ...
}
```

When getting `aboutMySelf`, i have the ff condition.

```
if (profile.getAboutMySelf() != null){
    ...
}
```

The problem is that I still encountered NPE for line `if (profile.getAboutMySelf() != null)`
Why? How to fix it?

stacktrace:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Profile.getAboutMySelf(Profile.java:263)
    at ...(.....java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
```

Comment: you need to check if profile is null or not. if (profile != null)

Comment: im certain that profile is not null, only the `aboutMySelf` since there are other properties of the profile

Comment: at Profile.getAboutMySelf(Profile.java:263). what u code in this line?

Comment: that refers to the getter `return aboutMySelf.getValue();`

Comment: maybe `aboutMySelf` have a null value. You have to check that.

Comment: is it ok to have `return (aboutMySelf == null)? "" : aboutMySelf.getValue();` in the getter?

Comment: ya, i think you can try that.